# Google Fit: save medical data

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

## Note

I couldn't find any similar question on StackOverflow. In the only threads I found, they asked about reading, not writing.

## Issue

I am integrating GoogleFit but I am not able to `insert` blood pressure data to the `HistoryApi`. I successfully login, but when adding data, I always get:

`Status{statusCode=TIMEOUT, resolution=null}`

I tried putting the code in a `AsyncTask` and inserting synchronously with `.await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)` but still getting the same error.

I also tried uninstalling `GoogleFit` and I have internet access via WiFi.

If it helps,`S Health` is working fine.

## Code

```
public static void saveBloodPressure(Context context, long timestampMillis, int systolic, int diastolic){

    // Create DataSource
    DataSource bloodPressureSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE)
            .setAppPackageName(context)
            .setStreamName(TAG + " - blood pressure")
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    // Create DataPoint with DataSource
    DataPoint bloodPressure = DataPoint.create(bloodPressureSource);
    bloodPressure.setTimestamp(timestampMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    bloodPressure.getValue(HealthFields.FIELD_BLOOD_PRESSURE_SYSTOLIC).setFloat(systolic);
    bloodPressure.getValue(HealthFields.FIELD_BLOOD_PRESSURE_DIASTOLIC).setFloat(diastolic);

    // Create DataSet
    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(bloodPressureSource);
    dataSet.add(bloodPressure);

    // Create Callback to manage Result
    ResultCallback<com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status> callback = new ResultCallback<com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status) {

            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.v("GoogleFit", "Success: " + status);
            }else{
                Log.v("GoogleFit", "Error: " + status);
            }
        }
    };

    // Execute insert
    Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mGoogleApiClient, dataSet)
            .setResultCallback(callback, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

In case someone asks, I will also put the `GoogleApiClient` initialization below.

## GoogleApiClient initialization

```
public static void initialize(final FragmentActivity activity){

    // Setup Callback listener
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks connectionCallbacks = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected! ");
            // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
            //subscribe();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
            // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                Log.i(TAG, "1 Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "2 Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
            }
        }
    };

    // Handle Failed connection
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener connectionFailed = new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {

            Log.i(TAG, "3 Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " + result.toString());

            Toast.makeText(activity, "4 Exception while connecting to Google Play services: " +
                    result.getErrorMessage() + ":" + result.getErrorCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };

    // Create Google Api Client
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks)
            .enableAutoManage(activity, connectionFailed)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .build();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a link to code snippet that explains clearly on how to READ Blood Pressure data using GoogleFit?

Comment: can you post the answer if you found out solution.. i've same issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though it seems a connection timeout error, it seems to me that you are missing something.

I'm not sure if this will help but FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE scope needs permissions.

Are you authorizing with Fitness API before calling Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData?

For which user are you inserting data?

See here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/permissions

And here (Authorization): https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/Fitness

Comment: It could be, I checked the links and I would say I already have `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. However, I am not sure about the user account. I can't remember any `setAccountName(String)` or `useDefaultAccount()`, so I will check it out on Monday and report back. Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't using any account, I added `setAccountName(String)` and ensured I declared `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` in my `manifest` but nothing changed. Still the same `TIMEOUT`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide on [Insert data](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#insert_data)

**Insert data**

> To insert data into the fitness history, first create a DataSet
>   instance:

```
// Set a start and end time for our data, using a start time of 1 hour before this moment.
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = new Date();
cal.setTime(now);
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

// Create a data source
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
        .setAppPackageName(this)
        .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .setStreamName(TAG + " - step count")
        .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
        .build();

// Create a data set
int stepCountDelta = 950;
DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
// For each data point, specify a start time, end time, and the data value -- in this case,
// the number of new steps.
DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint()
        .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).setInt(stepCountDelta);
dataSet.add(dataPoint);
```

> After you create a DataSet instance, use the HistoryApi.insertData
>   method and wait synchronously or provide a callback method to check
>   the status of the insertion.

```
// Then, invoke the History API to insert the data and await the result, which is // possible here because of the {@link AsyncTask}. Always include a timeout when calling // await() to prevent hanging that can occur from the service being shutdown because // of low memory or other conditions. Log.i(TAG, "Inserting the dataset in the History API."); com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus
=
        Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet)
                .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

// Before querying the data, check to see if the insertion succeeded. if (!insertStatus.isSuccess()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the dataset.");
    return null; }

// At this point, the data has been inserted and can be read. Log.i(TAG, "Data insert was successful!");
```

Comment: This code is from `HistoryApiSample` provided by Google on `GitHub`. I already have it and I have compared them several times. If you see any differences, please point them out, copy/pasting the example here is not contributing very much IMO.